# how to hide Bootstrap modal window if from field is not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to send form data and get response using jquery and display it in a modal window. every form field is required so i am using attb required. on click submit data should submit to jquery and fetch response. but if any of the field is empty error should display. now the problem is its also toggle the modal window. please see my code below.

```
<form name="newjoin" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="JoiningConform">

<label for="sponsorid">Name: <span class="req">*</span></label>
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" tabindex="1" required />

<button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="button btn btn-primary btn-large">Register</button>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade in">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <a class="btn btn-default pull-right" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="fa fa-remove"></span></a>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">CONGRALUATIONS</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h4>Text in a modal</h4>
                    <p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula.</p>
                    <div id="modal-div"></div>
                </div>

            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dalog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

my jquery is

```
$('form#JoiningConform').on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault()

    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'testmodal.php',
        data:$('form#JoiningConform').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            if(!response){
            $('#modal-div').html(response).modal('show');
             }
            }
        });
    });
```

my concern in if i click on button if any field is empty it should show only error after success response only modal Window should appear.

example image[image]

Comment: Would it not make more sense to validate the data before sending it?

Comment: i am using required attb in form its validating

Comment: Then that's the problem - you should look at fixing that.

Comment: You checked `if(!response){` but you didn't provide the content of the `response` variable...

Comment: first validate the fields, then submit the form.

Comment: @Dekel It shouldn't even be posting the data if it's empty.  No need to check the response until there actually should be one.

Comment: i just added image when i click on button. if the form field is empty its showing error but also model window showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...
First validate the name field.

```
$('form#JoiningConform').on('submit',function(event){
  event.preventDefault()
  var name = $('#name').val();
  if(name == ""){
    alert('error message');
    return false;
  }else{
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'testmodal.php',
        data:$('form#JoiningConform').serialize(),
        success: function(response){
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            $('#modal-div').html(response);
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: can we do validation in form using required= required html5

Comment: you are using ajax request on form submit, so when you hit the submit button ajax request will be execute even your fields are empty.....

Comment: in this case you can use jquery's .each() function to validate the all fields before submit the form.

Comment: i tried you code but still same problem please see question i add a image

Comment: Ok, i reviewed your code. Remove ( data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" ) from submit button.

Comment: check my answer, i have edited it. there is a modification in js code too. Check it and let me know.

Comment: the only correction is remove data-toggle and her and add $('#myModal').modal('show'); working grate